# How do i retrieve response from chrome browser to android app

Tags: android, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I had opened google chrome from my android app. It's working fine, but now I want to get the response URL from the chrome browser. And go back to the app after retrieving from that response. What to do for getting that response??

```
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("url"))
            startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: why do you need to get the URL from chrome?

Comment: I need an access token for a particular login credential it is received from one Url

Comment: then use retrofit

Comment: @AjayKS  I got a response from retrofit but i need to open the chrome browser first for login purposes. How to open the browser using retrofit is there any possible??

Comment: you can use webView for these purpose

Comment: and no need to get open Chrome for this

Comment: Amazon pay only support on chrome browser

Comment: have you checked this https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/payment-methods/amazon-pay/